# Column type to store 0..7 (octal) and bool values (oracle, postgres)

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, types, ddl

I create a table in Oracle and I need to make a single column with the following values 0, 1, .., 6, 7

```
CREATE TABLE "LOC_DB"."TI_TS" (
    "BIT" CHAR(1)  CONSTRAINT cons_ti_ts_bit CHECK (BIT IN     
('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7')) 
)
```

This was **the only one** best **way**? Or, maybe, we've got special types(octal number system)

(In case of **PostgreSQL** question interests **too**)

---

**Edit 1**

I was told that this practice is better:

```
CREATE TABLE "LOC_DB"."TI_TS" (
    "BIT" NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL  CONSTRAINT const_ti_ts_bit CHECK (BIT between 0 and 7), 
    "ACTIV" NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL  CONSTRAINT const_ti_ts_active CHECK (ACTIV in (0,1)), 
)
```

Thanks to Matt Allwood, a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Wouldn't integer with range be better than a char? I'd imagine that sorting/joining operations could better optimised?

Comment: I think you are right, cause this variant the best way only for "CHECK (BIT IN     
('0','1')"

Comment: For in `integer` column  it needs to be `0,1` not `'0', '1'` `'0'` is a string not a number. I would probably use `bit integer check (bit between 0 and 7)`